# What should we do with our blog content?

Tags: discussion, blog

Did you know we have a [blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/)?

At one time, Stack Exchange allowed sites to set up community blogs for people to contribute articles related to the site's subject that didn't fit the normal Q&A format.

Over time, a lot of these blogs have been neglected — like ours, which hasn't had a new article since July 2014 — so Stack Exchange is shutting down all blogs, and would like to know what we want to do with the content on ours.

Our options are:

- Freeze the content and leave it on site. This means no new articles, and no more comments on the existing articles. This is what will happen by default.
- Get a data dump and move the existing content to some other blogging platform, if people would like to start the blog up again and contribute to it.
- Delete the blog content (and pretend the whole thing never happened?).

SE would like an answer by the end of this month (November 2016), so what should we do with the blog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My personal preference is to freeze the content, no new post, no comments, but the content itself remains.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to @BMitch. (And that's not just because I have an article there.)(I don't think.)

Answer (score 0):

I say freeze the content and ensure that it stays around.